# Struggling with a basic math question in T. Tao's Analysis I

Tags: analysis

How to prove that a++ doesn't equal to a?

In one example, the book showed that 0 not equal to 0++ by this:
0++ cannot be equal to 0 by the Axiom "n++ not equal to 0 for every natural number n"

However, how do I prove that a++ doesn't equal to a?
I can't seem to use induction, as the number of steps seem to increment by one step, as a increments by one. e.g. to prove 0 not equal to 0++, one step only. to prove 1 not equal to 1++, 2 steps, using another Axiom "if n++ = m++, n=m".
Similarly, 3 steps for proving 2 not equal to 2++...

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you define what you mean by $n++$? From the context, I guess it should be something like incrementation.  Also, it would be helpful if you could make your problem self-contained by stating the axioms and results you are allowed to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write $n'$ instead of $n++$ for brevity. Let $P(n)$ be the statement $n' \neq n$. We have the base case $P(0)$. Assume $P(n)$ is true, that is, $n \neq n'$. By an axiom, different natural numbers have different successors (i.e. $'$ is injective), hence $n' \neq (n')'$, which is precisely $P(n')$.